# How to click on the 'Add User' button?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How can I click on 'Add User' button? I've tried with XPath, link text, CSS selector but none have worked.

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-8">
    <div class="file-upload btn btn-default" style="margin-top:4px">
        <span>Browse</span>
        <input accept=".csv" class="upload" id="File" name="File" value="" type="file">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field IsImporting must be a number." data-val-required="The IsImporting field is required." id="IsImporting" name="IsImporting" value="0" type="hidden">
    </div>
    <button type="Submit" id="btnImport" style="margin-top:4px" class="btn btn-default greybutton">Import</button>
    <a href="/Config/ImportFormat/UserImportFormat.csv" style="margin-top:4px" class="btn btn-default bluebutton">Download Sample</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="userAdd" style="margin-top:4px" class="btn btn-default bluebutton">Add User</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="userHierarchy" style="margin-top:4px;display:none;" class="btn btn-default bluebutton">User Hierarchy</a>
</div>
```

My code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.findElement(By.id("btnsubmit")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);

// Waiting for Loading left menu and Clicking on 'Setup' button
// driver.findElement(By.id("userAdd")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'leftpaneldiv\']/ul/li[1]")).click();

// Click on 'Users' module
driver.findElement((By.cssSelector(".treeview > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)"))).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB Question updated

Comment: There is no code

Comment: @RafałSokalski Please check now

Comment: @user2819306 , where is your Java code/selectors?

Comment: Give us your code when you try to click on that item by xpath

Answer (score 1):

According to the Add User link HTML you've posted, the locator you've used should work.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("userAdd")).click();
```

Since it doesn't, there are likely one of about three things that might be the issue.

1. The first thing you should generally do is to make sure that your locator is working. It should locate the element and ideally locate it uniquely on the page. To do this you will need to use the browser dev console. Run `$$("#userAdd")` in the console. If it comes back as 0, skip to Step 2. If it comes back as 1, skip to Step 3. If it comes back as >1, then that ID isn't unique on the page and you will need to add details to the locator so that it locates only the element you want. If you want help with that, you will need to add more of the surrounding HTML.
2. If the locator is working, see if the element is in an `IFRAME`. If it is, you will need to switch the context into the `IFRAME` before attempting to locate it.

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frameLocator));
   ```
3. The element may not be loaded when the page completes loading so you need to add a wait. If the element hasn't loaded before you attempt to click it, it will show as not found.

   ```
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("userAdd"))).click();
   ```

Comment: I tried with the first step and it returns '0', Any other method for finding the element?

Comment: Do the rest of the steps?

Comment: Yes, I've tried frame by using ID and Class name but still, it shows element not visible. Here is the code:   driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='userAdd']")).getText());
       driver.findElement(By.id("userAdd")).click();

Comment: `userAdd` is not the ID of the IFRAME. You should do some googling and find how to identify the IFRAME and switch to it properly.

Comment: Just want to confirm is it necessary 'iframe' tag under HTML for switching to frame, because in my code there is no 'iframe' tag so I've to assume some parent tag for the same, right?

Comment: If the desired element is not inside an IFRAME, you don't need to switch to any element. Skip to Step 3. This whole thing would be a lot easier/faster if you'd just share a link to the page.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared to invoke `click()` on the element with text as **Add User** you can use the following line of code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-default bluebutton' and @id='userAdd'][normalize-space()='Add User']")).click();
```

Comment: Here is my code- driver.findElement((By.xpath("//a[@href='/user']"))).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//a[text()='\r\n" + 
       "                                                Add User\r\n" + 
       "                                            ']"))).click();

Comment: @user2819306 `it's not working` doesn't throws any light on what's wrong happening. Update the question with your code trials and error stack trace

Comment: When there is an obvious element like this with ID= "userAdd" and its not working, in most cases it has some parent element, You have to switch to it. @JeffC explained it thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

As most obvious thing is:

**1. find by ID**

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("userAdd"));
el.click();
```

if is not that, You have some parent element that You need to switch to it.

**2. find frame or modal**

```
driver.switchTo().frame("modalFrameTitle");
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement()
```

and if it is **2.** go to step **1.** find element and interact with it.